# Satchels are not giving journals

Tags: diablo-iii

I would like to know why sometimes I find a satchel (like the Hunter's Satchel), and even though I haven't collected all of them (i.e. I might have missed one on the way), it only provides me with Gold. I double-check by clicking `ALT` and I'm sure I'm not missing it.

Is this a bug or is it built in, and why?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [your other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/102436/27134) I think you're expecting that any instance of a satchel if repeatedly collected will give you each subsequent journal from that series, however this is not the case. By design each satchel and journal is numbered and if you already have the journal you will simply get gold instead.

As mentioned in my answer to your other question, the locations of many of the Journals and Satchels is random, and only a random selection of each will spawn in a particular game world. You will not find all of them in one playthrough. Each of the spawns is unique, so picking up the same one twice is a possibility and the second time you pick it up you will get gold - this is normal.

The intention is that you will find the ones that you need at a later date on subsequent playthroughs.

Comment: Thank you again. I had found that some Journals (like King Leoric') appeared sequentially every time you picked up his satchel (either that or I was *really* lucky in the order I found them). So I assumed the same applied everywhere, and hence my questions.

Comment: No problem, some of them were particularly annoying to get just after the game came out because some regions on the map never actually spawned for the first month or so of the game being out - as far as I'm aware any instance of this problem no longer happens so each satchel/journal should now be available and should just be a case of being lucky enough for that section of the game world to be included in yours.

Comment: I suppose that's one way to keep getting us playing again and again haha.

Comment: @kalina I just finished the relevant acheivment, and can confirm that all journals are now obtainable.